# Which is the best approach to show blob in a tinymce editor textarea?

Tags: php, symfony, tinymce, fosuserbundle

I'm using Symfony2 and Twig to create a CMS.

In the "Manage Article" section, I use a bundle of tinymce to create rich content. The rich content is salved in database as a blob. This works perfectly.
The problem is when I want to edit an article. I don't know how to show the blob in the tinymce textarea. All I got is Resource id_ #.

I thought about creating an extension to twig, but I don't Know if there is any other simpler solution.

Can Someone help me?

Thanks in advanced.

Edit:
ContentType.php

```
namespace FEB\EmbeddableBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ContentType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('titulo', 'text', array('label' => 'Título :'))
                ->add('post', 'textarea', array(
                        'label' => 'Contenido a publicar :',
                        'attr' => array(
                                'class' => 'tinymce',
                                'data-theme' => 'advanced', // simple, advanced, bbcode
                                'rows' => 20,
                                'cols' =>  80
                                )

                     ))
                ->add('tipo', 'choice', array(
                        'label' => 'Clasificación de contenido :',
                        'empty_value' => 'Selecciona uno',
                        'choices' => array( 'video' => 'Video', 
                                            'imagen' => 'Imagen', 
                                            'hipertexto' => 'Hipertexto', 
                                            'unidad' => 'Artículo')
                        ))
                ->add('tags', 'entity', array(
                                                'label' => 'TAGS :',
                                                'class' =>    'FEBTagsBundle:Tag',
                                                'property' => 'tag',
                                                'empty_value' => 'Selecciona tags',
                                                'multiple' => true));
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'FEB\EmbeddableBundle\Entity\Content'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'feb_embeddablebundle_contenttype';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rich content is only text, right ? In this case, why do you use a [blob instead of the text type](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types) ?

Can you please show us your form type ?

Comment: No, the rich content are images too.
Edit my question with the formtype.

Comment: But that can be a solution n. 1. Because the images can be external links. the only thing that worries me is the size of text type.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to follow your advice, n.1. Works perfectly with text type.

Comment: "No, the rich content are images too" Does this mean that you can copy and paste images in TinyMCE and they are stores into the article content? I didn't know it was possible.

Comment: "text" type can be specified without defining the `length` parameter: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information